# Haskell without types

Tags: haskell, dynamic, types

Is it possible to disable or work around the type system in Haskell? There are situations where it is convenient to have everything untyped as in Forth and BCPL or monotyped as in Mathematica. I'm thinking along the lines of declaring everything as the same type or of disabling type checking altogether.

**Edit:** In conformance with SO principles, this is a narrow technical question, not a request for discussion of the relative merits of different programming approaches. To rephrase the question, "Can Haskell be used in a way such that avoidance of type conflicts is entirely the responsibility of the programmer?"

Comment: [no](http://dmwit.com/bacteria/grumpy.jpg)

Comment: Convenient, perhaps.  But note that whatever solution you use will not be culturally idiomatic Haskell, which is always strongly typed.  I suggest you leave your "inconveniences" behind and learn it the culturally normative way -- once you have spent some time with it, it will all fall into place and you will wonder why you thought you needed to disable the type checker.

Comment: +1 for use of "culturally normative" in answering a programming question.

Comment: `apt-get install racket`

Comment: @user287424 You will have to work harder to convince the folks here that "There are situations where it is convenient to have everything untyped". If you provide an example of such a situation, you may get more constructive answers that you can learn from. To your question: just store all your data as `String` and enjoy.

Comment: I find it really hard to understand why somebody would choose to learn Haskell and want to avoid the type system.  Haskell without the type system is like a BLT without the bacon.

Comment: @GabrielG  Nice analogy!  But a BLT without the bacon is also delicious!

Comment: Also: Orig Poster:  I agree that the short answer is "No, Haskell cannot be used without its type system."   However, besides Tikhon's suggestion of Data.Dynamic, also look at Template Haskell, and Dynamic Code Loading.  It might also be useful to google around for situations where you think dynamic typing is needed - there are alternate techniques. For example, laziness and multi-stage computation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also look at [`Data.Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) which allows you to have dynamically typed values in parts of your code without disabling type-checking throughout.

Comment: Of course one will still get errors from trying to manipulate data that has a value that makes no sense in whatever context. e.g. trying to add a string to an int. I don't think this module changes that.

Comment: @tikhon-jelvis, can you please update the link to Data.Dynamic the current link doesn't work.

Comment: @fshabashev Should be fixed now. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 8):

GHC 7.6 (not released yet) has a similar feature, `-fdefer-type-errors`:

http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DeferErrorsToRuntime

It will defer all type errors until runtime. It's not really untyped but it allows almost as much freedom.

Comment: As Pubby notes, this is *not* the same as dynamic typing.  Concretely, the difference is this: assume `-fdefer-type-errors` and consider the function `addOne :: a -> a` defined by `addOne x = x + 1`.  This clearly has a type error, and calling it as `addOne "x"` will error out appropriately.  However, `addOne (1 :: Int)` will (as I understand it) *also* error: even though the code would work by accident in that case, *it's still wrong*, and you'll get the error you *would* have gotten at compile time.

Comment: It does not provide freedom from the type system. It's not meant to turn off the type system, just delay it if the error in question is not relevant to `main` at compile time.

Answer (score 8):

Even with `fdefer-type-errors` one wouldn't be avoiding the type system. Nor does it really allow type independence. The point of the flag is to allow code with type errors to compile, so long as the errors are not called by the `Main` function. In particular, any code with a type error, when actually called by a Haskell interpreter, will still fail.

While the prospect of untyped functions in Haskell might be tempting, it's worth noting that the type system is really at the heart of the language. The code proves its own functionality in compilation, and the rigidity of the type system prevents a large number of errors.

Perhaps if you gave a specific example of the problem you're having, the community could address it. Interconverting between number types is something that I've asked about before, and there are a number of good tricks.

Comment: For the interested, two major application areas where this is relevant are exploratory programming (e.g. AI research) and symbolic math. See discussion among Lispers who tried Haskell but switched back because of the type system. See discussion on computer algebra about why the strongly typed Axiom system failed to gain acceptance among mathematicians.

Comment: Note: The above wording "The point of the flag is to allow code with type errors to compile, so long as the errors do not appear in Main. In particular, any code with a type error, when called at runtime, will still fail." is vague and potentially misleading.  I.e., what do "appear in `Main`" and "called at runtime" mean?  See [the paper](http://dreixel.net/research/pdf/epdtecp_draft.pdf) for better intuition.  E.g. `fst (True, 'a' && False)` evaluates to `True`, after being translated to `fst (True, error "Type error: Couldn't match Char with Bool")`.

Comment: On the other hand, see `addOne` [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747703/haskell-without-types#comment13967400_10747745) for an example where you might not expect an error but get one.  So, a better summary might be: type errors are localized (pushed to the leaves of the expression tree) as much as possible (heuristically), and then replaced with calls to `error`.  Haskell's lazy evaluation means that these error calls don't trigger if the (head) value of their expressions are not needed at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `fdefer-type-errors`  combined with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html offers what you need.